# Spring JAR File throws Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement Exception but I only use H2 for test profile

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, jar, h2

I have a spring boot with a mysql local db and a h2 db for test pruposes. Everything compiles and I can start the application. Once I build a jar file and pack it to a docker container via dockerfile. The startup message doesn't really make sense to me since I only use the h2 db for testing.
The migration for flyway starts and at the first create table statement, the sql syntax error appears (apparently h2 exception but I use mysql)
Below you can find my applications properties as well as my application-test.properties as well as the build.gradle and the docker file

app properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.flyway.enabled=true
spring.flyway.baseline-on-migrate=true
spring.flyway.table=flyway_order_schema_history
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/cf?enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2&useSSL=false&useServerPrepStmts=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://docker.for.win.localhost:3306/cf?enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2&useSSL=false&useServerPrepStmts=true
spring.jpa.database=mysql
spring.profiles.include=quartz
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace
server.port=8020
management.server.port=8029
```

app-test.properties

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
spring.application.name="cf-ms-test-runner"
spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true
spring.profiles.active=test
spring.flyway.enabled=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
server.servlet.context-path=/api/v1
spring.jpa.database=H2
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ANT_PATH_MATCHER
spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=NON_NULL
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:skel;MODE=MySQL;IGNORECASE=TRUE
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
```

```
Dockerfile
FROM openjdk:11.0.11-jre
VOLUME /tmp
COPY build/libs/*.jar  app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

> Error; (Works in mysql on app startup and is a generic quartz copy paste configuration)
> 2023-02-23T04:42:07.489897039Z Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS\000d\000a(\000d\000a    SCHED_NAME        VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,\000d\000a    JOB_NAME          VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,\000d\000a    JOB_GROUP         VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,\000d\000a    DESCRIPTION       VARCHAR(250) NULL,\000d\000a    JOB_CLASS_NAME    VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,\000d\000a    IS_DURABLE        BOOLEAN      NOT NULL,\000d\000a    IS_NONCONCURRENT  BOOLEAN      NOT NULL,\000d\000a    IS_UPDATE_DATA    BOOLEAN      NOT NULL,\000d\000a    REQUESTS_RECOVERY BOOLEAN      NOT NULL,\000d\000a    JOB_DATA          BLOB NULL,\000d\000a    PRIMARY KEY (SCHED_NAME, JOB_NAME, JOB_GROUP)\000d\000a) ENGINE[*]=InnoDB"; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:

I cleaned the build. I specified the h2 dialect. I am running out of ideas

Answer (score 0):

For all of you that experience the same issues. My problem was that the h2 database was configured as an application wide property, not only tests.

I followed the article and seperated the database to only be used in the test scope in the build gradle and defined a sperate jpa datasource as a @configuration bean

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-testing-separate-data-source